# Can the width or height of the browser screen be used to determine transition, or animation of a tag's opacity (css)? If so how?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Can the width or height of the browser screen be used to determine the transition, or animation of a tag's opacity (css)?  If so how?

For example as the width of the browser screen gets bigger, fonts become more clear.

Any resources are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What use would you actually have for this? It's unlikely users would resize the window to see transitions?

Comment: No because CSS is load at the beginning of the page loading. Without an user refreshing, the css file will not be loaded again ever. The only way to work with the browser window size css wise, is the use of media queries. However that will lead back to the issue that it is only loaded at the beginning and therefor cant be used to trigger animation if you resize the window. Technically speaking it would also be a very bad idea to implement such thing. What about mobile browsers that cant be resized for example. What about low resolution screens that cant be enlarged to see a clear website?

Answer (score 0):

For example this html

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Example title</h1>
</div>
```

Then use @media breakpoint to give each browser view size a differtent css.

```
/* first, give a default font-size (for a view less then 768px) */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* from 768px upwards */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

/* from 992px upwards */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}

/* from 1200px upwards */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```